# Android Email Auto complete

Tags: android, autocomplete

We are looking for a third party code which can help us to achieve email autocomplete in android similar to what is provided by [JQuery Plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Email-Autocomplete-Suggestion-Plugin)

[image: Email Autocomplete example]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for: 
https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete